# Efficient SQL query which gives me a list of users that have logged in at least once every single month

Tags: sql, loops, repeat

I need an efficient way (if possible) to give me a list of users that logged in every single month at least once.

The table is called login. the ID is user_id.

I need a list of users that have logged in at least once a month, for the last 36 months!
I could do a long list of nested subqueries like this;

```
select distinct user_id 
from login 
where extract (year from timestamp::date) = 2017
and extract (month from timestamp::date) = 1
and user_id in (
select user_id 
from login 
where extract (year from timestamp::date) = 2017
and extract (month from timestamp::date) = 2
and user_id in (
select user_id 
from login 
where extract (year from timestamp::date) = 2017
and extract (month from timestamp::date) = 3
and user_id in (..........
.........
```

I am on Amazon redshift

Thanks

Comment: count of number of logins group by year, month having count > 0

Comment: Please post a sample of the data. It's much harder to answer questions like this without seeing what the query is operating on.

Comment: I need a list of these ids, rather than a count

Comment: @PatJones it's literally two columns. User_id and timestamp. I don't see how posting sample data would help

Comment: Completely beside the point. It is proper procedure when asking questions to post sample data for the purpose of us being able to reproduce the situation in question. There are always multiple ways for ambiguity to creep into questions.

Answer (score 4):

This logic should work: get one row per user/month combination and count those rows:

```
select user_id
from
 ( select user_id --one row per user/month
   from login
   -- the last 36 months
   where timestamp >= timestamp '2015-02-01 00:00:00' 
   group by 
      user_id 
     ,extract (year from timestamp::date)
     ,extract (month from timestamp::date)
 ) as dt
group by user_id
having count(*) = 36 -- one row per month
```

Or using Redshift functions to truncate the timestamp to the 1st of month and then COUNT(DISTINCT):

```
select user_id
from login
where timestamp >= add_months(trunc('month', current_date),-35)         
group by user_id
having count(distinct date_trunc('month', timestamp)) = 36
```

Comment: As I recall, Amazon Redshift has a problem with `count(distinct)`, so this is definitely the best way to go.